# Can relative clauses be combined with adverbial clauses other than if-clauses?

Tags: relative-clauses

The following is from Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage*:

> Relative clauses can also be combined with *if*-clauses in sentences like the following.
>
> *I am enclosing an application form, **which** I should be grateful **if you would sign and return**.*

Then, can relative clauses also be combined with other kinds of adverbial clauses, for example *since*-clauses in sentences like the following?

> It seems something is wrong with this PC, **which** barely a month has passed **since I bought**.

Comment: As for the first example, I wouldn't judge that as a well-formed sentence, from *whom*??

Comment: "from" should be "form".  Do proof before you post, please, so we don't write into confusion.

Comment: @Xanne, sorry. I've fixed it.

Comment: @Clare, there was an error in the sentence. I'm sorry.

Comment: Is there a reason to think it is not acceptable? Or just the fact Swans doesn't mention them? Sounds totally fine to my ear

Comment: @Unrelated you find the OP's [last sentence](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22passed+since+I+bought.%22&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA2I3HmZ_XAhVHLhoKHX_eD4UQ_AUICSgA&biw=1307&bih=616&dpr=1.1) totally fine? It's clearly missing the complement (it).

Comment: @Mary-LouA Yes, and that is not even the biggest problem with the sentence. Maybe I was spoiled, growing up with an English teacher as a parent, but there is something seriously wrong about the "which barely" construct in the given context.

Comment: @Unrelated, it's the fact Swan doesn't mention them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, (it) is also missing in Swan's example after 'sign and return'. There must be something missing there because 'which' is a relative pronoun.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Isn't 'which' the complement? Surely you don't think 'which I should be grateful if you would sign and return it' sounds right

Comment: @Mari-LouA Phew. Thank goodness for you! There's a real issue here. :-) [Complements and Adjuncts guys, if you want to write a post!!]

Answer (score 2):

Swann missed a big generalization in limiting it to relative clauses and *if* clauses. Probly it was the "combined with" metaphor that did it. This is not cooking; you don't get a blend, you get a program.

They could have discovered (or rediscovered, depending on the publication date) [the Ross Constraints](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/ross.html), probably the most important syntactic discovery in the short history of generative grammar.

Details are available in Ross, J. R [*Constraints on Variables in Syntax*](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/haj/Ross_1967.html), 1967 .

The basic point that's applicable here is that the rule (aka transformation) that forms (relates) relative clauses from (to) their full form, called Relative Formation, is a rule that, as Ross put it, "operates over a variable", meaning that the movement of the relative pronoun to the front of the relative clause can come from indefinitely far down the chained trees of clauses, as long as it doesn't cross certain types of syntactic construction barriers.

E.g, the relative *that* (which could also be *who* or *whom*) is moved from position as object of *see*

- *the boy **that** the doctor told his receptionist he never wanted to **see ____** again*

Question Formation is another rule like that

- ***Who** did the doctor tell his receptionist he never wanted to **see ____** again?*

**Except** that there are exceptions.
These rules can't cross **islands**, which are kinds of constructions like coordinate structures

- *Frank cooked dinner and Bill washed up*  ~ **the dinner that Frank cooked and Bill washed up*

and complex noun phrases

- *She married the man who wrote that book* ~ **the book that she married the man who wrote*

These exceptions are the Ross Constraints. They apply to pretty  much every English sentence beyond *The ball is on the table*, which contains no islands.

Comment: +1 Nice links/resources. You don't mention specificaly why OP's second example is wonky. I'm assuming it's because the the clause from which the *wh*-word is extracted is part of an adjunct/adverbial? I looked through the relevant section of Ross, but couldn't find any adjunct constraint or similar. I'm assuming the first example's ok because the *if*-string is a complement of *grateful*?

Comment: Ross doesn't use the term "adjunct"; neither do I. The way it's used these days is not really syntactic. As for the second sentence, I don't really know whether it's covered by one of the constraints or not. All that means is that Ross didn't discover all of them.

Comment: What I meant by "adjunct" is just "modifier in clause structure'" (I mentioned looking though the Ross just cuz I didn't want you to think I was lazy and asking a question I couldn't be bothered to look up the answer for...) This Q is interesting for me because I was wondering whether, if adverbials/modifiers in clause structure do represent islands, examples like the OP's first one could maybe be used backwards as evidence that various *if*-strings are or aren't complements. And that would have a bearing on whether there were 1,2 or 3 *if*s in English. Most say 2. Pullum says 3. I say 1!

Comment: I have no idea how many _if_'s there are. Probly plenty; there's at least two _any_'s and three _do_'s, plus several hundred _the_'s. I'll hafta think what a "modifier in clause structure" means. You don't mean the Cycle, do you?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems something is wrong with this PC, which barely a month has passed since I bought.

This sentence doesn't work, because it is not obvious what `which` is referring to (although logically it must refer to the PC). Rather, rewrite it without the phrase about *time passing*.

> 1. It seems something is wrong with this PC, which I bought barely a month ago.
> 2. It seems something is wrong with this PC, which I have hardly used since I bought it a month ago.
> 3. It seems something is wrong with this PC, which I would like to return, since I only bought it a month ago.

**EDIT**

Note that there is a difference between `since` in your sentence, and `since` in the respect you would like to use it. If you can replace `since` with `as` or `because`, then it fits the pattern you are asking about. If you cannot, then it relates to a time period, which is something different altogether.

Comment: My question is "Can relative clauses be combined with adverbial clauses other than if-clauses?". If the sentence doesn't work, what difference from the example sentence in Swan's book with if-clause causes the problem?

Comment: The problem is that your sentence doesn't have a since-clause. It uses the word "since" in terms of a time period, but it is not the beginning of a clause. Therefore, your example doesn't fit the pattern in Swan's book. And, as far as I am aware, so long as you have a proper clause, you should be able to use Swan's idea with clauses starting with `if`, `because`, `since`, `although`, ...

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not the beginning of a clause"?

Comment: If `since` is used as a conjunction, then it is the beginning of a clause. If it is used as a preposition (related to time), then it is not the beginning of a clause.

This site explains it better: https://linguapress.com/grammar/points/since.htm

Comment: It is used as a conjunction even though the since-clause lacks the object of the verb "bought" (which is "this PC" of course) just like if-clause in Swan's example lacks the object of "sign and return".

Comment: I agree with Aki that *since* introduces a clause here. Cf. *Barely a month has passed since I bought this PC.* This works, because *since* can also introduce subordinate clauses in its temporal sense. In the sentence *I have lived here since 2014*, it is indeed a preposition (without subordinate clause). I do agree with Peter, though, that there is something different about the *since* sentence that makes it less felicitous. Is it indeed the word *since*, or is that a red herring?

Comment: @Cerberus I agree that your variation above of *Barely a month...* works. The `since` in the original sentence is likely a red herring, as you say, because if you remove `since I have bought` from the sentence, it is still broken. I can't put a formal spin on it, but the "which barely..." construct is not right.

Comment: @PeterAbolins: Mm but I don't think that proves it, the fact that it's broken if you remove *since I have bought*, because *which* is part of the clause that you remove: it's a highly complicated construction where two subordinate clauses are not so much nested as intertwined; you can't remove one without harming the other, but the exact rules are not entirely clear here.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the following sentences demonstrate that one can indeed combine relative clauses with adverbial clauses, using other than if-clauses:

1. Jeff skated slowly, that he should waste time on his journey.
2. Actions speak loudly, when they speak the truth.
3. Sally slept soundly, where she had run feverishly all day.
4. People come here, who love coffee.
5. Strategies work effectively, which take best advantage of the facts.
6. Even high level executives can get pushed out, whose motives are found corrupt.
7. He can advance quickly, whom nature has given good intellect.