# Doesn't Swan's example sentence violate adjunct island constraint?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, relative-clauses

After I posted the question [*Can relative clauses be combined with adverbial clauses other than if-clauses?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/416224/can-relative-clauses-be-combined-with-adverbial-clauses-other-than-if-clauses) and got no answer, I realized that this might be something to do with adjunct island constraint. But, then, another question came to my mind: Doesn't Swan's example sentence violate [adjunct island constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_(linguistics)#Adjunct_island_condition)?

I quote again from Michael Swan's Practical English Usage:

> Relative clauses can also be combined with if-clauses in sentences like the following.
>
> I am enclosing an application form, **which** I should be grateful **if you would sign and return**.

According to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)#Semantic_function)
if-clause is one of the conditional adjuncts.

Comment: 1. What's an "island adjunct constraint"? I've never heard of that before. 2. In what ways does Swan's sentence override it? His sentence is perfectly grammatical and makes semantic sense. I'll just wait until someone comments and/or writes an answer.

Comment: It still sounds wrong to me. I prefer _I would be grateful, were you to sign and return it._

Comment: @Mari-LouA, 1: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_(linguistics)#Adjunct_island_condition) is the explanation. 2: according to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)#Semantic_function) since-clause is one of the temporal adjuncts.

Comment: It seems OK to me. "Which" is a prenucleus that functions in the _if_ clause as object of "return".

Comment: @Aki I have no hesitation in admitting I am way out of my depth here. I would need all evening to understand the subject in the first link, the second is much easier. I look forward to seeing an answer :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I'm reading about syntax recently. About 2, I should have written "if-clause is one of conditional adjuncts". I mixed it up with my previous question.

Comment: I agree with @Mari-LouA here. Although it's stylistically unpleasant, the sentence is clear and syntactically correct. The question and sourcing point to the inherent difference between language and linguistics, and the patent absurdity of trying to learn the one through the application of the other - rather like learning to cook by reading a Wikipedia article on organic chemistry.

Comment: @BillJ, I know. Is that the violation of the constraint?

Comment: No. Constituents that do not allow gaps within them are often called called 'islands'. But that's not the case here: The prenucleus element "which" is cross-indexed to "gap" with _i_ : "I am enclosing an application form, which (_i_) I should be grateful if you would sign and return ___ (_i_). As you can see the constituent "if you would sign and return" permits a terminal gap "__".

Comment: What about the following example: *[DP What]i did he go home before Mary finished [DP e]i? from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_(linguistics)#Adjunct_island_condition)?

Comment: Ungrammatical of course. Can you get your head around X-Bar theory?

Comment: @Rob_Ster , sometimes [organic chemistry helps cooking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heston_Blumenthal), and [wikipedia](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cookbook:Table_of_Contents) too.

Comment: Incidentally, the "wh" movement that Wiki talks of is the X-Bar equivalent of the more general (and intuitive) "prenucleus-gap" approach that I used to analyse your example.

Comment: @BillJ, which means?

Comment: I read Aki’s links and wholly failed to see their relevance. Sorry, Aki.

Why does anyone think *should* and *would* have different meanings here than generally, please?

Take a squint at https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/will-would-shall-should for instance.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, which link are you talking about ?. This question is nothing to do with the difference between "would" and "should".

Comment: Uh… Your links, Aki; the ones you posted in your Question.

Both your main Question above and your first link from it, seem to rely for their real meaning on *would* or *should* if not both.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, read our discussion above. We are taking about whether adverbial clauses allow gaps within them.

Comment: Really? You have fun with and please, be sure to walk before you try to run.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, Yes, sir!